# Batch: gettin the last folder from a absolute path and compare with a string

Tags: batch-file

I using a Batch script into a .bat file to get the last folder from an absolute path and then compare with a string. For example I have: C:\Scripts\ (from where I start the run.bat) and sub-folders C:\Scripts\a\, C:\Scripts\b\results, C:\Scripts\c\results. I want to search for folders that have their names = "results" and when I found it to do some stuff (for example to increment a counter).

`set /A Counter=0`
`for /d /r %%F in (*.*) do (`
   `set path=%FF`
   `rem if the last folder from the path is = "results" then do some stuff`
   `if  path.contains("results") set /A Counter+=1` 
`)`

`echo %Counter%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set Counter=0
for /f %%F in ('dir /s/b/ad') do (
 FOR /f %%p IN ("%%F") DO (
 IF /i "%%~nxp"=="results" set /A Counter+=1
 )
)
ECHO %counter%
```

On the other hand,

```
DIR /s/ad/b |FINDSTR /i /e "\results"|FIND /c /v ""
```

will display the same count.

BUT Either of these methods WILL count ANY appearance of a "results" directory - whether it's at the lowest level or not, so it WILL be counted if `...\results` has subdirectories.